# Form Not minimizing when parent form of parent form is minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

Form(F1) Not minimizing when parent form(F3) of parent form(F2) is minimized.

Although Parent is minimizing

F3 is parent form of F2, and F2 is parent form of F1.

now when minimizing F3, F2 is getting minimized automatically but F1 is still on top.

Comment: Is F1 a MDI child? Are you opening F1 using Show method?

Comment: show your code for opening  the forms.

Comment: Yes Form is opened using show method

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the entire chain with the same owner. If you minimize the owner, then all owned forms will minimize.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form1().Show(Owner == null ? this : Owner);
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that closing the 'middle' window, won't minimize the last child window because it has another owner.

Opening the form like this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form1().Show(this);
    }
```

Will make every form close its ownedforms. (Closing the Main window won't close the last child)
I guess you want it all?

That behavior can be forced a bit by

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form1().Show(this);
    }

    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MINIMIZE)
                {
                    foreach (var frm in OwnedForms)
                    {
                        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: No i want to close the child form when closing the middle window.